# Display Indian Rupee symbol in Rshiny Datatable

Tags: r, unicode, encoding

How to display rupee symbol in Rshiny Datatable.`'\u20b9531'`.The value is 531 Indian rupees.How to display Indian rupee symbol

```
stri_unescape_unicode('\u20b9531')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear how the OP wanted to display.  If it is to create a new column, use

```
library(DT)
library(stringi)
datatable(data.frame(newcol =  stri_unescape_unicode('\u20b9531')))
```

outputs

[image]

---

If this needs to be in a shiny app (creating a new column in the dataset 'mpg')

```
library(ggplot2) 
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    DT::dataTableOutput("tbl")
  )

)

server <- function(input, output) {      
  output$tbl <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable(
       transform(mpg, newcol = stri_unescape_unicode('\u20b9531'))
    ))}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

outputs

[image]